# NODE JS- Trying Update it gives - npm WARN unmet dependency

Tags: node.js, npm

When I execute npm install npm -g, I get this error

```
C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\npm -> C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\nod
e_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\async-some requires dezalgo@'^1.0.2' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\dezalgo,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 1.0.3
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\fs-vacuum requires graceful-fs@'^4.1.2' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\graceful-fs,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 4.1.2
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\fs-vacuum requires path-is-inside@'^1.0.1' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\path-is-inside,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 1.0.1
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\fs-vacuum requires rimraf@'^2.2.8' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\rimraf,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 2.4.3
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\fs-write-stream-atomic requires graceful-fs@'^4.1.2' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\graceful-fs,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 4.1.2
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\fstream requires graceful-fs@'^4.1.2' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\graceful-fs,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 4.1.2
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\glob requires inflight@'^1.0.4' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\inflight,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 1.0.4
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\glob requires once@'^1.3.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\once,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 1.3.2
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\inflight requires once@'^1.3.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\once,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 1.3.2
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\init-package-json requires glob@'^5.0.3' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\glob,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 5.0.14
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\init-package-json requires npm-package-arg@'^4.0.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\npm-package-arg,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 4.0.2
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\init-package-json requires validate-npm-package-name@'^2.0.1' but wil
l load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\validate-npm-package-name,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 2.2.2
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\node-gyp requires fstream@'^1.0.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\fstream,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 1.0.8
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\node-gyp requires graceful-fs@'^4.1.2' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\graceful-fs,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 4.1.2
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\node-gyp requires mkdirp@'^0.5.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\mkdirp,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.5.1
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\normalize-package-data requires hosted-git-info@'^2.0.2' but will loa
d
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\hosted-git-info,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 2.1.4
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\npm-package-arg requires hosted-git-info@'^2.1.4' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\hosted-git-info,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 2.1.4
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\npm-registry-client requires chownr@'^1.0.1' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\chownr,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 1.0.1
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\npm-registry-client requires graceful-fs@'^4.1.2' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\graceful-fs,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 4.1.2
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\npm-registry-client requires mkdirp@'^0.5.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\mkdirp,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.5.1
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\npm-registry-client requires normalize-package-data@'~1.0.1 || ^2.0.0
' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\normalize-package-data,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 2.3.4
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\npm-registry-client requires npm-package-arg@'^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0' but w
ill load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\npm-package-arg,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 4.0.2
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\npm-registry-client requires once@'^1.3.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\once,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 1.3.2
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\npm-registry-client requires retry@'^0.8.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\retry,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.8.0
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\npm-registry-client requires slide@'^1.1.3' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\slide,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 1.1.6
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\read-cmd-shim requires graceful-fs@'^4.1.2' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\graceful-fs,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 4.1.2
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\read-installed requires read-package-json@'^2.0.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\read-package-json,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 2.0.1
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\read-package-json requires glob@'^5.0.3' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\glob,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 5.0.14
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\read-package-json requires normalize-package-data@'^2.0.0' but will l
oad
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\normalize-package-data,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 2.3.4
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\read-package-tree requires dezalgo@'^1.0.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\dezalgo,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 1.0.3
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\read-package-tree requires once@'^1.3.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\once,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 1.3.2
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\read-package-tree requires read-package-json@'^2.0.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\read-package-json,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 2.0.1
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\realize-package-specifier requires dezalgo@'^1.0.1' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\dezalgo,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 1.0.3
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\realize-package-specifier requires npm-package-arg@'^4.0.0' but will
load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\npm-package-arg,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 4.0.2
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\rimraf requires glob@'^5.0.14' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\glob,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 5.0.14
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\sha requires graceful-fs@'^4.1.2' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\graceful-fs,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 4.1.2
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\tar requires fstream@'^1.0.2' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\fstream,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 1.0.8
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\write-file-atomic requires graceful-fs@'^4.1.2' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\graceful-fs,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 4.1.2
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\write-file-atomic requires slide@'^1.1.5' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\slide,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 1.1.6
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\glob requires inflight@'^1.0.4' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\inflight,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 1.0.4
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\glob requires once@'^1.3.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\once,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 1.3.2
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\tar requires fstream@'^1.0.2' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\fstream,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 1.0.8
npm@3.3.4 C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm
```

I also tried to install cordoova and get some error, I think its the sam issue. I am begineer in NODE and need som help about that.

It would be good great help for me !.